# Firefox 4 + application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, firefox4

I recently updated to Firefox 4 and I'm all of a sudden getting this error when I visit my ASP.NET MVC site. No errors using Firefox 3.x and other browsers. I'm running on IIS 7.

```
You have chosen to open

which is a: application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml
from: http://dev.wittychat.com

What should Firefox do with this file?
```

Anyone know how to fix this? I assume it might be a MIME setting or something related?

Comment: Are you using 51 Degrees Mobile Device Detection? http://51degrees.codeplex.com/

Comment: Awesome that worked by upgrading, can't believe I forgot about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed by upgrading to the latest 51 Degrees Detection package, thanks Michael!

Comment: Cool - we had the exact same problem and upgrading worked for us, too.